# Azure ARM Template json function error: usage issue

Tags: azure, devops, azure-application-insights

i'm using following template while deploying.

```
{

  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "alertName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "defaultValue": "{{alertinginsights.alert.alertName}}"
    },
    "alertDescription": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "defaultValue": "{{alertinginsights.alert.alertDescription}}"
    },
    "alertAppInsights": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "{{alertinginsights.alertAppInsights}}"
    },
    "alertSourceQuery": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "{{alertinginsights.alert.alertSourceQuery}}"
    },
    "alertTriggerThreshold": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "{{alertinginsights.alert.alertTriggerThreshold}}"
    },
    "alertTriggerOperator": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "{{alertinginsights.alert.alertTriggerOperator}}",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Equals",
        "NotEquals",
        "GreaterThan",
        "GreaterThanOrEqual",
        "LessThan",
        "LessThanOrEqual"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Operator comparing the current value with the threshold value."
      }
    },
    "alertSeverity": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "{{alertinginsights.alert.alertSeverity}}",
      "allowedValues": [
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Severity of alert {0,1,2,3,4}"
      }
    },
    "alertScheduleFrequency": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "{{alertinginsights.alert.alertScheduleFrequency}}",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Select the frequency on how often the query should be run"
      }
    },
    "alertScheduleTime": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "{{alertinginsights.alert.alertScheduleTime}}",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Select a time span over which to execute the above query"
      }
    },
   "resource": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "{{alertinginsights.resource}}"
    },
    "webhookPayload": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "{{alertinginsights.webHookPayload}}",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Webhook in JSON to be sent to action groups"
      }
    },
    "actionGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "{{alertinginsights.alert.actionGroupName}}"
    },
    "isResultCount":{
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "{{alertAppInsights.alert.isResultCount}}"
    },
    "triggerObject":{
      "type":"object",
      "defaultValue":"[json(alertAppInsights.alert.triggerObject)]"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "alertTagBase": "hidden-link:/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/",
    "alertTagMid": "/providers/microsoft.insights/components/",
    "alertTag": "[concat(variables('alertTagBase'),parameters('resource'),variables('alertTagMid'),parameters('alertAppInsights'))]",
    "alertSourceBaseId":<rgBase>,
    "alertSourceMidId": "/providers/microsoft.insights/components/",
    "alertSourceId": "[concat(variables('alertSourceBaseId'),parameters('resource'),variables('alertSourceMidId'),parameters('alertAppInsights'))]",
    "actionGroup": "[concat(<rgBase>, parameters('resource'),'/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/',parameters('actionGroupName'))]",
    "alertStatus": "true"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
        "name": "[parameters('alertName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules",
        "location": "southcentralus",
        "apiVersion": "2018-04-16",
        "tags": {
          "[variables('alertTag')]": "Resource"
        },
        "properties": {
          "description": "[parameters('alertDescription')]",
          "enabled": "[variables('alertStatus')]",
          "source": {
            "query": "[parameters('alertSourceQuery')]",
            "dataSourceId": "[variables('alertSourceId')]"
          },
          "schedule": {
            "frequencyInMinutes": "[parameters('alertScheduleFrequency')]",
            "timeWindowInMinutes": "[parameters('alertScheduleTime')]"
          },
          "action": {
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction",
            "severity": "[parameters('alertSeverity')]",
            "aznsAction": {
              "actionGroup": [
                "[variables('actionGroup')]"
              ],
              "customWebhookPayload": "[parameters('webhookPayload')]"
            },
            "trigger":"[parameters('triggerObject')]"
          }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

The value of `alertAppInsights.alert.triggerObject` is: `"{\"thresholdOperator\":\"GreaterThan\",\"threshold\":0}"`.

But I'm getting this error:

```
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"InvalidTemplate\",\r\n \"message\": \"Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'triggerObject' at line '89' and column '21' is not valid: Unable to parse language expression 'json(alertAppInsights.alert.triggerObject)': expected token 'LeftParenthesis' and actual 'Dot'.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.\"\r\n }\r\n}"}]
}
```

Not sure usage of json is invalid or something I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe it should be `[json(variables('alertAppInsights')).alert.triggerObject]`

Comment: @juunas I'm passing config context based and `alertAppInsights.*` is how all the values are being accessed. The problem is with usage of  `json`

Answer (score 0):

ok, i'm a bit confused with your template, but any function expects a string\int\object input, so `json()` isnt anything different, it should take an input like this `json('something')`. if you want to pass in object, you have to use a parameter\variable for that. you cannot really pass it inline (at least I never seen that).

Also, the template looks extremely weird, i'd be surprised it would work...

Answer (score 0):

When I try to validate your JSON I get the following error:
[image]

I would correct the syntax on line 99 and test teh JSON again in Visual Studio or any other JSON validator untill you have no errors and then try to deploy again.